# How can i use Jmeter plugin (libraries) to create a Http and Https load test in Java Desktop application

Tags: java, testing, load, jmeter

Am looking for some examples of Java classes That uses Jmeter plug-in (libraries) that allow me to make the same work of load test with the same way of Jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use JMeter API to either run existing .jmx script file or to create a load test from scratch.

See chapter 4 (Running A JMeter Test Through a Program) (from Java code)of [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) guide for details.